# Plotting term document matrix from clipboard

Tags: r

I want to plot a term document matrix, but am having trouble generating a corpus. I want to be able to generate a corpus from selecting text and copying it to clipboard. For example, I want a plotted TDM off of 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum data.

This part here is just for drawing in word data from lipsum.com

```
library("tm")

#generate a corpus from clipboard
clipboard2 <- read.table("clipboard",sep="\r")
```

The next part would (if it worked), split clipboard2 into a bunch of documents from which to get correlations off of. **I think there's an easier solution here than creating documents which are then re-read back in for corpus' sake.**

```
#how many docs to print out for correlations sake
for (i in 1:10) {
  start <- floor(1 + (i-1) * nrow(clipboard2) / 10)
  end <- i * nrow(clipboard2) / 10
  write.table(clipboard2[start:end, 1], 
              paste0("C:/Users/me/Documents/", i ,".txt", collapse=""), sep="\t")
}
```

Pulling in the corpus of documents into a variable. Everything from this point on works fine if I manually split lipsum.com data into a few documents in some directory.

```
#Corpus collection
feedback <- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/me/Documents/"))
```

Removing words and whitespace, though there might be some redundancy here. Then creating the TDM.

```
#Cleanup
feedback <- tm_map(feedback, stripWhitespace)
feedback <- tm_map(feedback, tolower)
feedback <- tm_map(feedback, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#TDM creation (redundant?)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(feedback, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                    removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                                    stopwords = TRUE))
```

And finally, plotting the TDM. No issues here.

```
#plotting TDM
plot(tdm, 
     terms = findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 70), 
     corThreshold = 0.6)
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear to me which part you are asking about, but as far as reading in the clipboard directly into a corpus, you could use

```
dd <- read.table("clipboard", sep="\r", stringsAsFactors=F)
feedback <- Corpus(VectorSource(dd$V1))
```

That will create a new document for each paragraph. But the idea is that you can use a character vector as a source so you can collapse/merge elements in the vector first to create more complex documents.

Comment: For some sample text like a book from Gutenberg.org, paragraphs get split on multiple lines and pushes the corThreshold way down to be able to see any sort of detail. Is there a command to collapse/merge sizable chunks in the vector?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what command you are running or what you are seeing. But it sounds unrelated to this question. You might be better off starting a new one.